# Which words require "go" and which "grow" as a linking verb?

Tags: collocations, linking-verbs

Which words go with **go** and which with **grow** as a linking verb?

> 1. bald
> 2. impatient
> 3. bad
> 4. mad
> 5. gray
> 6. bored
> 7. old
> 8. blind
> 9. calm

Our teacher says that The linking verb **go** is used for colors and bad adjectives like **bald, deaf, blind**, etc. but we also use **grow** for **impatient**. Then how can we decide which one to use?

Comment: Your teacher is quite correct that we *tend* to use ***go*** for "colors and bad adjectives", but this isn't a fixed rule. [*His face grew pink*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+face+grew+pink%22), for example, occurs almost as often as *His face **went** pink* in Google Books. But if you hear, for example,  *John **went** religious last year* (as opposed to ***grew*** or ***became***), you can probably assume the speaker himself thinks of "being religious" as a bad rather than a neutral or good thing. So it *is* a useful usage distinction to be aware of in general.

Comment: Obviously one would not exepct **grow** with **bald** (lack of growth), but **grow bald** is a good *oxymoron*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now cold you please answer the questions above?

Comment: The "generic" answer is that there are no absolute rules regarding whether ***go*** and/or ***grow*** (or indeed other verbs, such as ***get***) can be used in any given context. So if you were hoping for a "bulletproof, definitive" classification for each of your *particular* nine adjectives, I'm afraid there isn't one. There might be a "logical" explanation for why *He went mad* and *He grew angry* occur far more often than *He grew mad* or *He went angry*, but I'm not sure delving into something as specific as that would be the best way of "answering" this question.

Comment: @Peter: *And so he continued riding along and playing upon his fiddle for many years, [**until his head grew bald**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22until+his+head+grew+bald%22) and his face was wrinkled and his bushy eyebrows became as white as snow.* That's from L. Frank Baum, who wrote *The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*, so I think it's safe to assume it's a "valid" usage. Though I see no obvious reason why he couldn't have written *until his head **went** bald and his face **grew** wrinkled*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **go** bald
2. **grow** impatient
3. **go** bad
4. **go** mad
5. **go** gray
6. **grow** bored
7. **grow** old
8. **go** blind
9. **get** calm

But as FumbleFingers explains in his comments, there seems to be no *rule* that governs the use of "go" and "grow".  In some cases the use is a complete oxymoron, like "grow smaller".  Unfortunately it's more memorization.

Comment: But you used get at the end?

Comment: @TahaAkbari yes, on purpose.  Sometimes you have to question what you're taught.  "Grow calm" is fine too, depending on context.  Personally, I prefer "get calm".

Comment: Ideally, the verb for "grow smaller" would be *shrink*.